# Have a dynamic this.variable i.e this.(the dynamic name here).

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which gets a div's name as input and then there's a library which allows for smooth scrolling.

```
 goToIndex(divName){
    console.log("DivName", divName);
    scrollToComponent(this.divName,{offset : 0,align : 'top',duration : 1500});
```

Now, this.divname in console is giving out undefined.
this.divname should take the place of

this.skills or

this.hello
basically whatever the div's name input is passed to it.

I'm writing the code in react

Comment: Please paste all the component's code in the question

Comment: That's what square bracket notation is for: this[divName]

Comment: @PatrickHund Aren't this.something and this[something] supposed to be the same, your advice works, thanks for that. But can you shed a it more light that why didn't this.something work

Comment: What are you expecting `this.divName` to be?

Comment: No, this.something and this['something'] would be the same (note the quotes)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That clears it up